# Power Saving Mode in iOS 9 - What do devs need to know?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios9

Does this affect anything we're currently doing with core location or background processes? How about how often appWillTerminate is called or SIGKILL is sent to our apps?

Answer (score 1):

The document says that in low power mode the it "may"

```
Pause discretionary and background activities, including networking
```

I highly doubt that in low power mode appwillterminate notification get called more often.

Also there is a notification for entering low power mode

```
NSProcessInfoPowerStateDidChangeNotification
```

You can check the current mode with

```
NSProcessInfo.processInfo().lowPowerModeEnabled
```

You can find the complete documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LowPowerMode.html).